# How to connect DataGrip to postgres on google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, postgres-8.4

I've installed Postgres on Google Compute engine.
I can create users, schemas and tables.
I can connect to the Google Compute engine with PyCharm, remote configuration.
But I can't connect DataGrip to the Postgres.

It looks like the Posgres port is open (port 5432):

```
...@instance-2:~$ netstat -ntpl
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

It looks like the connection is getting blocked. when trying telnet

```
telnet <GCP Compute engine IP> 5432
```

was not successful

tried using "SSH Tunnel" in DataGrip. while the SSH Tunnel connects well, I still can't
connect to the Postgres

Can someone advice how to make sure that the google cloud settings do not block connection
or advice how to properly set the connection? Thanks

There was a suggestion to edit the "pg_hba.conf". From what I understand I need to add
my specific IP. Would I need to change it every time I change working location?
Other suggestions?

Comment: This is missing the actual error given by DataGrip when attempting to connect to the DBMS, I doubt "I can't connect" is among the errors it can present. Understanding the actual problem might help solving it

Answer (score 0):

You PostgreSQL database access is controlled by the `pg_hba.conf` you mentioned and `postgresql.conf` files.

You're able to SSH into your VM because it listens on a port 22 and accepts connections from avery IP:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

For the moment it looks like you have a default configuration that allows only connections from localhost (127.0.0.1).

`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

For the server to accept connections to your DB from every IP find a `postgresql.conf` file and change a line from `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`.

Now restart the service `sudo service postgresql reload` and check if your server accepts connections from all IP's:

```
$ netstat -nlt
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

We see that the port 5432 is open for any IP's.

Next edit your `pg_hba.conf` file and add this at the end:

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Now restart postgresql server (to be sure the changes will be taken into account) and try to connect;

```
$ psql -h your-postgres-server-ip -U user
Password for user user:
psql (9.4.1, server 9.4.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
```

However this poses some security risk due to exposing your DB to the internet and allowing connections from any IP. So - if you know the IP's (or ranges) from which you will be connecting then you can put them in `pg_hba.conf'.

You may also have a look at the documentation describing [`pg_hba.conf` structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) here and [how to configure PostgreSQL's incomming connections](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html).

And - **if you're super paranoid then you can change the IP in the `pg_hba.conf` every time you change your location/ip** to connect to it.

Comment: Opening up the database to every IP is a terrible idea, using DataGrip's SSH tunnel would expose the DBMS much less and still achieve the desired result.